# How would I open multiple files inside a folder without including the exact file path for each file?

Tags: .net, windows, powershell, batch-file, cmd

I want to write a script that will open all the files in a certain folder. There are many files to open and it would be more tedious to type each one of the file paths out in a batch file. Is there a way I can write something to open these files using only the folder path?

Comment: Why so many tags? If you don't know where to start, you might want to ask this on [Programmers Stack Exchange](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/). If you've already tried something, please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/31621161/edit) to include the code you have already tried.

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty simple in PowerShell.

```psh
Get-ChildItem "C:\temp" | ForEach-Object{Invoke-Item $_.FullName}
```

Given the folder `"C:\temp"` we use the cmdlet `Invoke-Item` to execute each file just in the same way as if you double clicked on the file in Windows Explorer. Each file will open with its default assigned program.

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate through all the files in the folder, and start them as you go.

(Batch)

```
@echo off

for /f %%a in ('dir /s /b drive:\Path\To\Your\Folder') do start %%a

pause
```

**Note:** Do NOT put this in the same folder as the files, as you will create an infinite loop.